# Python nltk.util ngram wrong output format

Tags: python

I am new to Python and doing my first course work exercise. Trying to turn a bit of text into trigram tokens but I'm not getting the expected output:

```
    from nltk.util import ngrams

    def process_text(text, n = 1):
           tokens = [token for token in text.split(" ") if token != ""]
           tokenised = list(ngrams(tokens, n))
           return tokenised

    process_text("knife pot spoon hammer nail", 3)
```

##### Output:

```
              [('knife', 'pot', 'spoon'),
              ('pot', 'spoon', 'hammer'),
              ('spoon', 'hammer', 'nail')]
```

##### Output should look like this:

```
             ['knife pot spoon',
              'pot spoon hammer',
              'spoon hammer nail]
```

Comment: Usually, when you're working with lists of words, you do want then separated into a list, exactly as you have it.  You can get your result by combining them yourself: `tokenised = list(' '.join(k) for k in ngrams(tokens, n)))`.

Comment: Thanks so much. That does the trick. But I take your point that it's not what one would normally work with.